# How can I set the Id attribute to Kendo grid data picker column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am trying to set ID attribute like  `Id = "datepicker"` to the column and also trying to set Min and Max date for the `datepicker`

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.InvoiceDate)
              .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
```